# Hilbert's Nullstellensatz for analytic functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

In Demailly's book [complex analytic and differential geometry, p97](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf), he states that $F_{V(F), 0} = \sqrt{F}$, where $F$ is an ideal of the ring of holomorphic functions in an open subset of $\mathbb C^{n}$ containing $0$, $V(F)$ are the common zeros of the elements in $F$, and $\sqrt{F}$ is the radical of $F$. What confuses me is that the statement seems to suggest $0 \in V(F)$ which does not seem to be correct. One can simply take the ideal generated by a holomorphic function which does not vanish at $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The germ of a holomorphic function that does not vanish at $0$ is invertible because as a power series, it has an inverse in the ring of formal power series, which can then be shown to be convergent as well. So the ideal generated by that would be the whole ring. Its vanishing set $V(F)$ would then be empty.